# TypeScript Compile Options: module vs target

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

Trying to have some basic understanding about module and target.

I would like to know the difference between module and target compile options in a typical tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```

What happens if I provide the following options:

module: commonjs, target: es6

module: es6, target: commonjs

module: commonjs, target: commonjs

Comment: Target can not be commonjs. It can only be: 'es3' (default), 'es5', or 'es6'. Have you read the [Compiler Options doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) ?

Comment: An important correction to Paleo's answer: [Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) actually says that >>"ES6" and "ES2015" values **may be used** when targeting **"ES5" or lower**.<<

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding "target" and "module" in tsconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993811/understanding-target-and-module-in-tsconfig)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**A more detailed explanation is here : [Understanding "target" and "module" in tsconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993811/understanding-target-and-module-in-tsconfig)**

---

See also: [Understanding "target" and "module" in tsconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993811/understanding-target-and-module-in-tsconfig).

Here is a quote from the documentation [on compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> **--target**
>
> Specify ECMAScript target version: 'es3' (default), 'es5', or 'es6'.
>
> **--module**
>
> Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', or 'es2015'.
>
> - Only 'amd' and 'system' can be used in conjunction with --outFile.
> - 'es6' and 'es2015' values may be used when targeting ES5 or lower.

Comment: Here is a better explanation for this module vs target confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993811/understanding-target-and-module-in-tsconfig

Answer (score 22):

There are 2 different things. `--target` simply means which version of ECMAScript you're using to code. `--module` simply means which module system you're using such as `commonjs` for Node or ES module for all that supports it and what not.

Comment: what do you mean by "you're using"? You can be using module system to resolve dependencies or you can be using modules to package your output. Or there are other things where you can "use" one or another module system or langauge level

Comment: It basically means your own code or the code you're writing. `target` affects your code (excluding whatever from your `node_modules`). `Modules` is about module resolution that affects your local files and how it can read something from your node_modules. TypeScript config should mainly affecting your own code because it is not a bundler. With that being said, you can write ES2020 code with native esm while your packages can be written in ES5 and RequireJS.

Answer (score 16):

The "target" property is used to specify the JavaScript version your TypeScript code will eventually compile into. The "module" property specifies the type of the module syntax your compiled (TS-->JS) code will use. For instance if you set the module property to "commonJS", your compiled code will use "require/module.exports" to import/export. The module property will not however affect the rest of the compiled code. For the sake of clarity, please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61215252/8659116