# Exporting and Importing modules in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to export a simple class Like this:
**functions.ts**

```
 export class components{
        private m_name:string;
        private m_level:string;
    
        constructor(name:string,level:string){
            this.m_name=name;
            this.m_level=level;
        }
    
    }
```

**app.ts**

```
import {components} from './functions';
let c1 = new components("Tushar","Admin");
```

I am including the js file(app.js) that's being transpiled into index.html to see it on the console if it's working.
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Feedback
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src= "app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the **tsconfig.json** File :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "commonjs",
     "strict": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "skipLibCheck": true,
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
 }
}
```

I get an error saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
> at app.js:2

I do not understand why it isn't working. I tried changing the target to es6 but doesn't help. Though this works fine on [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/opxinhlx-tusharroy)

Comment: You might find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60127854/9078341

Comment: Though this provides some information about compiler options in tsconfig.json but i am unable to get to a solution.

Comment: oh, you had `module.exports` at the end of the file. Remove that on if you are using es6 `export`.

Comment: You need to also change the target to es6 and module to 2015.