# What is module option in tsconfig used for?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, commonjs, tsconfig

I am trying to understand the typescript module compiler option.

I went through typescript documentation - [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)
It  says module option is to `Specify module code generation`.

What does that mean?

Does it mean if I put module option as `commonjs`, then the compiler compiles the code to commonjs? But then we have options like `esnext, es16`. After I went through [Docs: Difference between esnext, es6, es2015 module targets](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24082), I understood that `import() expressions are understood in esnext`. Anyway the purpose of compiler is to compile the code into browser understandable syntax(commonjs).  So compiling code to the module type given doesn't make sense.

So does it mean the module type you give tells the compiler in what syntax the code is written? Meaning from which code it has to compile it to commonjs? But then we have module type `commonjs` which is frequently used but we almost never write code in pure commonjs syntax.

[what is the purpose of tsconfig.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413533/what-is-the-purpose-of-tsconfig-json) stackoverflow answer says `module specifies module manager`. I don't understand what that means.

I also went through [Understanding “target” and “module” in tsconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993811/understanding-target-and-module-in-tsconfig) and [tsconfig module options - does 'System' refer to SystemJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142665/tsconfig-module-options-does-system-refer-to-systemjs).

None of these seem to answer my question properly.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions: {
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

TLDR; `module` in tsconfig.json tells the compiler what syntax to use for the modules in the emitted .js files. Frequently used values are `"commonjs"` (require/module.exports) or `"ES2015"` (import/export keywords), but there are other module systems. `module` affects the module syntax of emitted code while `target` affects the rest.

- **What does `Specify module code generation` mean?**

`"module"` in tsconfig.json tells the Typescript (TS) compiler what module syntax
to use when the files are compiled to Javascript (JS).

When you set `"module"` to `"commonjs"` in tsconfig.json, this means that the modules in the compiled .js files will use the commonJS (CJS) syntax, so `var x = require(...)` and `module.exports = {...}` to import and export.
If you changed `"module"` to `"ES2015"` for example, the compiled code would use the `import` and `export` keywords used in ES2015 module syntax. For an overview of the other syntaxes you can take a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#code-generation-for-modules).

There are several different module systems with CJS and the
native ES Module (ESM) format probably being the ones most widely used.
What to choose depends on your requirements. If it's for a server-side project
that uses Node.js then probably CJS, if it's for an Angular front-end application
than perhaps ESM (*or their own NgModules but that's going beyond scope here*).
A somewhat similar situation is library and package designs and how you would
like to expose them to consumers. This depends on what sort of users are going to consume
the code, what are they working with (browser, Node) and which of the module systems
is best suited for the job?

ES Modules are now the built-in standard for importing/exporting modules in JS but back when there was no native solution other module systems were designed: This is why we also have CJS, AMD and UMD modules around. They are not all obsolete, CJS is still used a lot in Node.js and the AMD module loader for example allows non-JS imports which can be useful in some cases.
Nowadays, all the modern browsers and Node 13.2.0+ support the ESM format ([see this page for compatibility data and more background on modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)).

**But then we have options like esnext**

Newer JS versions sometimes contain more features for module import/export.
setting `"module"` to `"ESNext"` enables support for these features which often are not added to official specifications yet. Such as the `import(...)` expression which is a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports).

**Does it mean if I put module option as commonjs, then the compiler compiles the code to commonjs?**

The `"module"` setting does not affect the rest of the code, `"target"` is used for that instead and specifies what JS version the outputs should be compatible with.
This has been explained in other threads, I'm just adding it here for clarity.
Say you want to use `require(...)` and `module.exports = {...}` in a Node project but also want the code to utilise ES2015 features like `let` and `const` in the code (for readability/performance/other reasons).
In this case you would set `"module"` to `"commonjs"` and `"target"` to `"ES2015"` in tsconfig.

**Anyway the purpose of compiler is to compile the code into browser understandable syntax(commonjs).**

Yes, the compiler has to turn TS code into JS that a browser understands.
However, JS is no longer limited to browsers, Node runs in other environments (servers) for example. CJS was in fact intended as a server-side module format while AMD modules were/are used for browser imports/exports.

**So does it mean the module type you give tells the compiler in what syntax the code is written?**

It tells the compiler in what syntax to write the modules in the output .js files

Comment: Great explanation I couldn't find in other places :)

Comment: This is a really good, clear explanation of an otherwise complex topic. Thank you.

Comment: Simply the best explanation I found

Comment: Emphasizing that esnext is the module you want for nodejs 12 or later output with typescript 4.5 and later as the module output is dynamically determined by the node version used to compile the typescript. This avoid generating a lot of convoluted unreadable javascript code from the typescript source as the later versions of javascript in node support a lot of the typescript language extensions natively.

Comment: It is not clear if "module" settings affects the browser at all? I understand, "target" settings affects the browser, so trying to be on the safe side say "target": "es5". However using setting "module": "esnext", is it affects the browser, or is it just for webpack, so the browser compatibility will not play?

Comment: Honestly this has to be the most confusing thing about TypeScript new comers. The devs should add aliases like "compiledModule" and "compiledJsVersion" or something like that (the hell "target" comes from?)

Comment: If you're getting complaint about the 'requires' from commonjs you can add to tsconfig compilerOptions:
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,